# Printing Ordered Dates from a Switch Statement

Tags: java, date, loops, switch-statement

I am attempting to write a loop that will get its values from my switch statement.  I want it to print out the dates in order each on their own line, such as:
1/1
1/2
1/3
...
12/31

I have attempted to write it myself, but I'm not entirely sure how to assign the months in correct order to the 3 cases I have in the switch statement.

Below is the switch statement I am using:

```
int month = 0;
    int yearInt = year;
    int totalDays = 0;

    switch (month) {
    case 1:
        totalDays = 30;
        break;
    case 2:
        if (((yearInt % 4 == 0) && !(yearInt % 100 == 0))
                || (yearInt % 400 == 0))
            totalDays = 29;
        else
            totalDays = 28;
        break;
    default:
        totalDays = 31;
        break;
```

Comment: Can't understand your question. Can you please explain a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? January is assumed 1

```
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 8:
case 10:
case 12:
    totalDays = 31;
    break;
case 2:
    if (((yearInt % 4 == 0) && !(yearInt % 100 == 0))
            || (yearInt % 400 == 0))
        totalDays = 29;
    else
        totalDays = 28;
    break;
default:
    totalDays = 30;
    break;
```

Note that the fall-through syntax I used is sometimes considered harmfull

Comment: beat me by about 30 seconds...  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can as well get the desired result using built-in methods:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, yearInt);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    int totalDays = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Note: Value of `month` starts from `0` (`0` for January, `1` for February..).